# How to convert continuous realtime emotion and probability output into float arrays

Tags: python, arrays, types, protocols, osc

I'm using someone else's trained Python realtime facial recognition model to continuously output probability values for 'happy', 'sad' ...(7 emotions overall). I'm sending this data across to Processing using OSC. But I can't seem to figure out a way to split the Python data into 7 arrays that I can send across. Currently, I'm doing this:

```
 for (i, (emotion, prob)) in enumerate(zip(EMOTIONS, preds)):
    # CODE BELOW DRAWS BOXES WITH DIFFERENT PROBABILITY VALUES
            text = "{}: {:.2f}%".format(emotion, prob * 100)
            # draw the label + probability bar on the canvas
           # emoji_face = feelings_faces[np.argmax(preds)]


            w = int(prob * 300)
            cv2.rectangle(canvas, (7, (i * 35) + 5),
            (w, (i * 35) + 35), (0, 0, 255), -1)
            cv2.putText(canvas, text, (10, (i * 35) + 23),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45,
            (255, 255, 255), 2)
            cv2.putText(frameClone, label, (fX, fY - 10),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45, (0, 0, 255), 2)
            cv2.rectangle(frameClone, (fX, fY), (fX + fW, fY + fH),
                          (0, 0, 255), 2)
   #RELEVANT SECTION - SENDING THE 'float' VALUE
            client.send_message("/filter", float(prob))
```

This however means that I receive one float value at the given frame rate. So I would receive a float variable x which would keep updating from the probability value for Happy, to Angry, to Sad, to Disgusted.... instead I want 7 such variables x1,x2,x3,x4...x7 being outputted each for the probability value of each expression 'Happy', 'Angry'... Any suggestions?

Comment: can't you just send `dict(zip(EMOTIONS, preds))` to your client that should give you probabilites of all emotions for every frame, right?

Comment: Sorry if this a noob question but how would I receive a dict type in Javascript/Processing, and how do you refer to specific indicies ie if I want to get the probability value of Happy only.

Comment: you can send it as a json, as the body of the request, probably post (although it is possible in get too)